# replacing dynamic string refs with useRef in hooks for little complicated scenarios

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ref

I have a react class based component with usage of dynamic refs. I need to refactor that code to
hooks using useRef dynamically.

```
export default class App extends Component {

   navigate(item) {
    if (item === 'home') {
      Object.keys(this.refs).map(function(ref) {
        if (ref.endsWith('ul') && !ref.startsWith(item)) {
          this.refs[ref].style.borderLeftColor = '#fff';
        }
      }, this);
      this.context.router.history.replace('/');
    } 
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {item} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul ref={item + 'ul'} onClick={() => { navigate(item);}}>
            <span>{item}</span>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How to change that this string ref with useRef in hooks as it feels little confused particularly when ref={item + 'ul'} is given as string ref instead of ref="itemref".